# Gcloud error 401: REquest had invalid authentication credentials

Tags: gcloud, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm working on a project where I need to access a Gcloud service account. However, I've been encountering issues with authentication. This is the following error from my command prompt:

My command:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \ 
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize \ 
-d @sync-request.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

At the current moment, I have done the following: I set my environment variable, "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", to hold the path to my service account's JSON key file, I opened my cmd in the directory where the key file is located, I ran the command. Is there anything else I'm missing?

The documentation I am following is from https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#windows

Comment: I don't want to see your authorization token, but when you inspect it does it look right?  I get that you have to set the header but the Bearer parts seems like that you should be part of the authentication mechanism itself.  When it talks about auth application-defautl it says "These credentials are only used by Google client libraries in your own application." which is not promising to me. Never used glocud so I could be entirely wrong.

Comment: You can try creating a [new service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) and download the [JSON key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) just to have fresh credentials and try following the instructions for setting up the path in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.

`gcloud` does not use ADC; setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` does not configure `gcloud`.

You should (have not tried) be able to use `gcloud auth activate-service-account ...` and then `gcloud auth print-access-token`.

Or you can just use a regular (human|non-service) account and `gcloud auth print-access-token`.

Or, you can use `gcloud auth application-default login` and then `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` but the two go together.

Don't quote the token in header:

```sh
TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"                     # Either
TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" # Or

curl \
--silent \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--data @sync-request.json \
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I am attempting to authenticate my application as a service account via the command prompt. According to the documentation, I can use the Google Cloud Client Libraries and ADC to automatically find my service account credentials. Here is the document to which I am referring to: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#windows.

Comment: You can use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` only with Google's SDKs. You can use `print-access-tokem` values with curl as I showed. But `print-access-token` can only use a`gcloud auth`'d credentials. Either a regular Google (human) account or a service account. For the latter you must `gcloud auth activate-service-account`. You can even `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` but you must `gcloud auth application-default login` first. This last approach is no longer recommended and using it this way is a little unusual.

Comment: ... this is because, this is|was a way to avoid using a service account by emulating one with human credentials. If you just have code using Google SDKs, create a service account and use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

Comment: Also, if you're not aware of it, check out [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l). It's useful for munging tokens.